# how to directly import now() from datetime.datetime submodule

Tags: python, datetime, import, git-submodules

**Background:** I have a few tight loops in a Python program that are called repeatedly, which include the `datetime.datetime.now()` method, as well as the `datetime.datetime.min` and `datetime.datetime.max` attributes.  For optimization, I would like to import them into the local namespace, avoiding the repeated, unnecessary module hierarchy name look-up, like so:

```
from datetime.datetime import now, min, max
```

However, Python complains:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my_code.py", line 1, in <module>
    from datetime.datetime import now, min, max
ImportError: No module named datetime
```

**Question:**  Why doesn't the above submodule import work?

**Workaround:**  I can instead do this:

```
import datetime
dt_now = datetime.datetime.now
dt_min = datetime.datetime.min
dt_max = datetime.datetime.max
```

But, I'm curious why the more traditional approach does not work?  Why can I not import methods and properties directly from the datetime.dateime submodule? ... And, is there any reason to avoid the above workaround (besides readability, outsmarting myself, etc.)?

Thanks!

Comment: you are probably better off not importing max and min anyway  or you could have unexpected results when you go to call the builtin min or max functions

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, you are right.  That's why I changed the name in my workaround, but I was too lazy to add "as" to rename them in my original example. :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`datetime.datetime` is not a submodule.  `datetime` is a class within the `datetime` module.  `now` is a method of that class.  You can't use `from...import...` to import individual methods of a class.  You can only use it to import individual modules from a package, or individual objects that exist at the top level of a module.

As for your workaround, if you want shorthand, I find it more readable to do this:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dt.now()
# you can also use dt.max, dt.min, etc.
```

If you really want to put those methods directly in local variables, then your workaround makes sense.